# Error assigning values to combobox (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, ttk

i am getting an error whenever i try to add values to a combobox (python 2.7). Below is my code.

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class StartApp:
    def __init__(self,Runtime):
        self.Runtime = Runtime
        Runtime.title("My App")

        self.frame1 = Frame(Runtime, width=500)
        self.frame1.grid(sticky='nsew')        

        self.SearchName_Combobox = Combobox(self.frame1).grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=10)
        self.SearchName_Combobox['values'] = [1,2,3]

root = Tk()
the_app = StartApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

i get the following error.
*TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment*

Comment: I know 
"self.SearchName_Combobox = Combobox(self.frame1, values='1,2,3')" works but I intend to use "self.SearchName_Combobox['values'] = [1,2,3]" in a function.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the issue

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class StartApp:
    def __init__(self,Runtime):
        self.Runtime = Runtime
        Runtime.title("My App")

        self.frame1 = Frame(Runtime, width=500)
        self.frame1.grid(sticky='nsew')        

        **self.SearchName_Combobox = Combobox(self.frame1)**
        self.SearchName_Combobox['values'] = [1,2,3]
        **self.SearchName_Combobox.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=10)**

root = Tk()
the_app = StartApp(root)
```

root.mainloop()

---

I tried to explain what i changed but apparently the bold formatting didn't work. This was the change

Original:
self.SearchName_Combobox = Combobox(self.frame1).grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=10)

Corrected: 
self.SearchName_Combobox = Combobox(self.frame1)
self.SearchName_Combobox.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=10)**

Comment: Your answer would be better if you gave an explanation for what you changed. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.